# Enable/access bug tracking for Team Foundation server 2010 with basic setup wizard

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging

I need(want) to enable/access the bug tracking for team foundation server 2010 beta 2, and I don't know how to get it.

Can somebody tell me how or point me were to read?

Answer (score 2):

If you've got your Team Project setup, then you should just be able to add bug work items depending on which process template you selected when you installed the product.  Open team explorer and connect to your server and assuming you have access you should be able to enter bugs.

[Team System Development Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/default.aspx)

[Team System Rangers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/ee358786.aspx)